# Function inside of a function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to JavaScript and am trying to implement something like below.
Use case: implementing authentication with Firebase + JavaScript

In my sign in form, I have a JavaScript as below:

```
// Sign in
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
.then((user) => {
    console.log(user)
})
.catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(errorMessage);
});
```

I am trying to call a second function inside of the signInWithEmailAndPassword method. This other function looks like this:

```
function getMyToken() {
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
        return idToken
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle error
        console.log(error)
        return null
    });
}
```

How can I do that? I tried as below but getting an error:

```
// Sign in
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
.then((user) => {
    console.log(user)
    var isTokenDefined = getMyToken();
    if (isTokenDefined) {
       //Redirect to index.html
    }
})
.catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(errorMessage);
});
```

Error I am getting: isTokenDefined is undefined

Comment: `getMyToken` is an asynchronous function, it takes some time to resolve. You can't just do  `var isTokenDefined = getMyToken()` and expect `isTokenDefined` to be defined. This is a very common question, I have marked it as duplicate.

Comment: if you need user where you have isTokenDefined available, you'll need to do something like `.then((user) => getMyToken().then(isTokenDefined => ......))`

Comment: What would be the best way to resolve what I am trying to do?

Comment: best way? use `async`/`await`

Comment: @Bravo, I am trying to understand async/await. Would you help me with an example based on my example above?